# Failed to allocate a 1850507580 byte allocation with 1048480 free bytes and 382MB until OOM

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou colocando uma imagem de 728k em uma ImageView e quando rodo o app no android studio dá esse pau na aplicação:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1850507580 byte allocation with 1048480 free bytes and 382MB until OOM

Alguém sabe o por que disso?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.gustavo.easypasse.LoginActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_easy_passe_b" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCPF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="CPF"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSenha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Senha"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAcesse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Acesse" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCadastro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cadastro" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem ver o seu código fica difícil. Mas com certeza ele está tentando colocar na memória algo bem maior do que 728kB. Isso daí dá 1,72 GB.

Comment: Faltou memória no seu dispositivo.

Comment: Queres ver o xml @VictorStafusa?

Comment: Gustavo, o melhor jeito para fazer o teste para saber se essa imagem é o problema é removê-la e ver no que dá

Comment: Pus o código no post, pode olhar.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, já removi a imagem algumas vezes e sempre que tiro ela, o app funciona legal!!
Será o problema por a imagem ser .svg e depois convertido em .jpg ou .png?

Comment: Acabei de dar uma olhada nos detalhes da imagem... Ela tem Dimensões 12974 × 3962, será esse o problema?